# Simple decision tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, machine-learning

I've been trying to get better at Haskell for a while, and have recently been working on a lot of small projects with it. [This](https://gitlab.com/jb25uiuc/decision-tree/tree/f128ab2f7ffd0ab6670c480d1b301e95be449768) constructs a binary decision tree.

The command to run it is:

`stack exec decision-tree-exe <threshold> <training file> <testing file>`

where threshold is in the range (0,1].

I think I've gotten a lot better, but I'm still having problems, especially with performance and readability. For this project, I took a more top down approach, implementing functions after using them. src/DecisionTree.hs is where the bulk of the logic is, and the file is pretty much in order of writing. I would love to get some feedback from some more experienced people on where I might improve.

```
module DecisionTree where

import Data.List (genericLength, maximumBy, nub)
import Data.Map (elemAt, foldlWithKey', fromListWith)
import Data.Ord

data DecisionTree a b
  = Node ([a] -> Bool) (DecisionTree a b) (DecisionTree a b)
  | Leaf b

type Dataset cat attrs = [(cat, [attrs])]

type Threshold = Double

type Splitter c a = ([a] -> Bool, Dataset c a, Dataset c a)

apply :: DecisionTree a b -> [a] -> b
apply (Leaf b) _ = b
apply (Node f l r) a =
  case f a of
    False -> apply l a
    True -> apply r a

train ::
     (Ord c)
  => (Dataset c a -> Maybe (Splitter c a))
  -> Dataset c a
  -> DecisionTree a c
train splitter dataset =
  case splitter dataset of
    Just (partitioner, left, right) ->
      Node partitioner (train splitter left) (train splitter right)
    Nothing -> Leaf majority
  where
    classCounts = fromListWith (+) $ map (\k -> (fst k, 1)) dataset
    majority = fst $ foldlWithKey' max (elemAt 0 classCounts) classCounts
    max acc k v
      | v > snd acc = (k, v)
      | otherwise = acc

giniSplitter ::
     (Ord a, Ord c) => Threshold -> Dataset c a -> Maybe (Splitter c a)
giniSplitter threshold dataset =
  case fst maxDelta > threshold of
    True -> Just $ snd maxDelta
    False -> Nothing
  where
    attrs = nub . concat . snd . unzip $ dataset
    partitioner a = (a `elem`)
    delta a = giniDelta (partitioner a) dataset
    maxDelta = maximumBy (comparing fst) $ map delta attrs

giniDelta :: (Eq c) => ([a] -> Bool) -> Dataset c a -> (Double, Splitter c a)
giniDelta partitioner dataset =
  ( gini dataset - (d1 / d * gini left + d2 / d * gini right)
  , (partitioner, left, right))
  where
    left = filter (not . partitioner . snd) dataset
    right = filter (partitioner . snd) dataset
    d1 = genericLength left
    d2 = genericLength right
    d = genericLength dataset

gini :: (Eq c) => Dataset c a -> Double
gini d = 1 - sum [(pj c) ** 2 | c <- nub . fst . unzip $ d]
  where
    pj c = genericLength (filter ((== c) . fst) d) / genericLength d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few random comments:

1. Both `elemAt` and `maximumBy` give hints that you're expecting to operate on non-empty structures. Maybe give `Data.List.NonEmpty` a try.
2. A few places could be more clear with more pattern matching. E.g. `max (k1, v1) k2 v2` instead of `max acc k v`. Or `(maxDelta, splitter) = maximumBy …`
3. `map snd` is more conventional than `snd . unzip`. I suspect it would be more efficient too but I might be wrong.
4. In several places you're traversing the same list multiple times. In general, it's better to avoid this as it's likely to force the spine of the (potentially large) list in memory. You might be able to merge these multiple traversals into one (e.g. using the `foldl` package). More likely, you should simply use `vector`.
5. In `giniDelta` you could use `Data.List.partition` to construct `left` and `right`.
6. Apply top-down ordering in your `where`-clauses. E.g. in `train`, `majority` should come first as it is the declaration that is referenced from the main function body.

**EDIT:** All in all I think readability is actually pretty good!